# data frame and series in python to create excel column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, series

is there a way to create either data frames or series in python from an excel sheet that has multiple rows and columns such as

[image]

and expect the output to be all in one column

[image]
tried different codes for data frames and series non did what I expected and series are doing letter by letter in the code that I used

```
import numpy as np
sr=pd.read_excel('eng.xlsx')
s1=pd.Series(sr, expand=True)
print s1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with remove `MultiIndex` by [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) with `drop=True`:

```
s1 = sr.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
```

Or convert values to `numpy array` with [`numpy.ravel`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) or [`numpy.flatten`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.flatten.html):

```
s1 = pd.Series(sr.values.ravel())
s1 = pd.Series(sr.values.flatten())
```

**Sample**:

```
sr = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('ab'),
        'B':list('cd'),
        'C':list('ef'),
})

print (sr)
   A  B  C
0  a  c  e
1  b  d  f

s1 = sr.stack().reset_index(drop=True)
print (s1)
0    a
1    c
2    e
3    b
4    d
5    f
dtype: object
```

Comment: and if I dont want it to pirnt the cells with non value what shall I add to the code because some rows has more words in it and its printing non

Comment: @IbrahimOzaeri - there are not removed values by `stack`? So it means it is no missing values and for remove need `s1 = s1[s1 != 'non']`, because `s1 = s1.dropna()` I think not working

Comment: even with adding !=non its still printing the empty cells as in this picture https://ibb.co/PjBqLFR

Comment: @IbrahimOzaeri - Can you check `s1 = s1.dropna()` ?